# How does Youtube generate the share and comment sections

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, youtube

Youtube seems to have a good design in hiding its source codes and making the page size smaller.  When I look at the page source of Share and Comment sections, I could not find the content there.  For example, if I want to search "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6m" in share section and "sahara" in the comment section of the page source, I can not find them even though I can see it in the page (see the image below).
[image]

I thought the final page is in static html.  The content should all been displayed. How can Youtube achieve this?  Through AJAX calls or HTML5?

Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about reverse-engineering the code behind a commercial website.

Comment: I've edited the question back into its original form which I answered. Don: If you want to ask a new question, click the "Ask Question" button in the upper right. Don't edit an existing question into a new one.

Comment: @duskwuff I edit it because others vote to close the question.  I just don't understand that Chrome and other tools offer to reverse-engineer the codes.  The contents and technologies of any public sites should be open to discuss.  Why is it not good for Stackoverflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't static HTML anymore. If you look carefully, you'll notice the comments popping into view as you scroll down.

If you look through the contents of the Network table of the Chrome web inspector, you'll see the comments being loaded through AJAX. The URL involved suggests that the change is related to Google+ -- the URL that the comments are being loaded from currently starts with:

```
https://plus.googleapis.com/_/im/_/widget/render/comments
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  What technologies can achieve that now?  AJAX?  HTML5?

Comment: AJAX can be used to do this, yes.